# Within a nested for loop, how can I print tab and carriage return delimited groups of data?

Tags: python

My code is going through frames in a video, and sampling a set of x,y points that I previously selected in each frame.  The x,y points are contained in `boxes`.

For each frame in the video, there are `len(boxes)` pixel values I want printed on one line with tabs between them, followed by carriage return for the next frame.  I'm actually doing some ratioing of pixel values here, but that's not really relevant.  I just need to get output with tabs where I want them and not carriage returns.

```
print("size of boxes: ", len(boxes))
for i in range (0, video.__len__(), 2):
    for j in range(0, len(boxes)):
        print(str(float(video[i][boxes[j]])/(video[i+1][boxes[j]])) + str('\t'))
    print('\n')
```

I get this instead of the tab delimited groups of 7 that I want:

```
 ('size of boxes: ', 7)
    0.485893416928  
    0.602201257862  
    0.584277620397  
    0.759312320917  
    0.663671373556  
    0.70249017038   
    0.724576271186  


    0.496379726468  
    0.632218844985  
    0.532608695652  
    0.699738903394  
    0.731774415406  
    0.693527080581  
    0.772058823529
```

Comment: You should never use `x.__len__()`... That's what `len(x)` is for

Comment: You should also never use `for i in range(0, len(xs)): foo(xs[i])`... That's what `for x in xs: foo(x)` is for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `end` argument to print to override the default behavior of printing a newline:

```
print(video[i][boxes[j]] / video[i+1][boxes[j]], end='\t')
```

Note that if this is python 3, the `float` should also be unnecessary. If you're in python 2, you can get all the relevant features with:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
```

---

If I were writing this, I'd do it:

```
s = '\n'.join(
    '\t'.join(
        str(v1[b] / v2[b])
        for b in boxes
    )
    for v1, v2 in zip(video[0::2], video[1::2])
)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Eric's answer but I want to point out that for Python 2 having a comma at the end of the print statement prevented python from automatically adding a carriage return.  Also, apparently Python 3.0 uses print() as a function, whereas Python 2 uses print not as a function but rather as a statement.  This means that I could optionally also eliminate the parenthesis after print() in my original code, or add a space: print ().

For my scrappy original code, the above meant simply adding a comma after the print statement

```
print("size of boxes: ", len(boxes))
for i in range (0, video.__len__(), 2):
    for j in range(0, len(boxes)):
        t0 = time.clock()
        print str(float(video[i][boxes[j]])/(video[i+1][boxes[j]])), "\t",
    print ('\n')
```

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function, division` and you're good to go with my code on python 2